# Error in downloading gcloud project’s IAM policy

Tags: google-iam

I am new to google cloud and trying to explore. I tried to download my project’s IAM policy as a CSV file. However, I'm having an error:

```
(gcloud.projects.get-iam-policy) Format [csv] requires a non-empty projection.
```

Can someone help me with this?

Run the command —format csv flag, expecting to extract the iam policy in csv file. Error mentioned showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is expected when you try to extract IAM policy in csv format as there's no built-in functionality for this. However you can instead opt to use json to extract the policies then just convert it to csv after.
Enter the below commands in the shell:

```
$gcloud projects get-iam-policy your-project --format json > iam.json
```

This will output a json file with the format:

```
{
   "bindings": [
   {
       "members": [
       ...
       ],
       "role": "..."
   },
   {
       "members": [
           "...",
           "..."
       ],
       "role": "..."
   }
   ],
   "etag": "...",
   "version": ...
}
```

Hope this helps.